Getting Python's unittest results immediately during test-run execution
I do large test runs (hours to days with hundreds of tests) and want to see the progress in a spreadsheet. In this spreadsheet, the same result that unittest prints to the console (meaning ., F or E) shall be inserted immediately after each individual test is finished.
I know about this answer that successfully retrieves the correct unittest result in the tearDown method if it falls into the categories PASS, FAIL or ERROR.
However, there are more ways a test can come to an end: There's also SKIPPED, EXPECTED_FAILURE and UNEXPECTED_SUCCESS.
I used the following code to handle at least PASS, FAIL, ERROR and SKIPPED:
import unittest


class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def tearDown(self):
        def list2reason(exc_list):
            """Converts test-result structure to str."""
            if exc_list and exc_list[-1][0] is self:
                return exc_list[-1][1]

        if hasattr(self, '_feedErrorsToResult'):
            # for Python 3.4 - 3.10
            result = self.defaultTestResult()
            self._feedErrorsToResult(result, self._outcome.errors)
            result.skipped = self._outcome.skipped
        else:
            # for Python 3.11+
            result = self._outcome.result

        failureMsg = list2reason(result.failures)
        errorMsg   = list2reason(result.errors)
        skippedMsg = list2reason(result.skipped)

        isFailure  = bool(failureMsg)
        isError    = bool(errorMsg)
        isSkipped  = bool(skippedMsg)

        # Here, I want to add the result to a spreadsheet.
        # For simplicity, I'll just print the result.
        print()
        if isFailure:
            print('FAIL')
        elif isError:
            print('ERROR')
        elif isSkipped:
            print('SKIPPED')
        else:
            print('PASS')

    def test_01_pass(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)

    def test_02_fail(self):
        self.assertTrue(False)

    def test_03_error(self):
        raise ZeroDivisionError
    
    def test_04_skip(self):
        self.skipTest('')

    @unittest.expectedFailure
    def test_05_expectedFailure(self):
        self.assertTrue(False)

    @unittest.expectedFailure
    def test_06_unexpectedSuccess(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()

I was able to retrieve EXPECTED_FAILURE as well by changing the last paragraph in tearDown to this:
        expFailure    = self._outcome.expectedFailure
        expFailureMsg = f'{expFailure[0].__name__}: {expFailure[1]}' if expFailure else None
        isExpFailure  = bool(expFailureMsg)

        # Here, I want to add the result to a spreadsheet.
        # For simplicity, I'll just print the result.
        print()
        if isFailure:
            print('FAIL')
        elif isError:
            print('ERROR')
        elif isSkipped:
            print('SKIPPED')
        elif isSkipped:
            print('SKIPPED')
        elif isExpFailure:
            print('EXPECTED_FAILURE')
        else:
            print('PASS')

However, I cannot for the life of me get the info on UNEXPECTED_SUCCESS, so my code incorrectly treats this case as a PASS.
My findings:

self._outcome.expecting_failure is always set to False
self._outcome.success is always set to True
self._outcome.result.unexpectedSuccesses is always []
self._outcome.result.wasSuccessful() returns the overall test-run result, not just from the current test

And by always, I mean always. I do not remember seeing anything different for any result type. When looking at the data stored in self._outcome , I do not see a way to get the info I need.
Does anyone have an idea? Is pytest any better in that regard?

Is there a specific reason you're trying to handle this in tearDown? That's designed for cleanup, not for recording test results. TestResult is the intended interface for examining test results.

@user2357112: As I read the TestResult docu, the TestResult is returned by TestRunner.run(), so after all tests have been run. My intent is to get the result immediately after each test, because a complete test run takes many hours and I want to see the progress in the spreadsheet.
I also tried adding a custom cleanup method with the code above via self.addCleanup(self.cusomCleanup) in the setUp method (where would I rather do that?). Unfortunately, I get the same behavior.

You can probably extend TestResult.addError, addFailure, addSuccess, addSkip, addExpectedFailure, and addUnexpectedSuccess to handle reporting results as tests run.

As the docs say above those methods, "The following methods of the TestResult class are used to maintain the internal data structures, and may be extended in subclasses to support additional reporting requirements. This is particularly useful in building tools which support interactive reporting while tests are being run."

@user2357112: Thank you, that is a very helpful hint and should be the answer to my question. I just did not know this. I don't understand why my issue is closed, but i will try to rename the title (since actually getting the results in tearDown is not needed as long as I get the live results somehow.

It still says that my question is closed and debugging details are needed. I'm not that experienced on this platform, and it seems silly to me to make my question even longer (especially since the anwer is so simple: Don't do it in tearDown, extend TestResult!), but I added a full MRE, since the review seems to demand it. I  think it would be helpful for people to have the question on this platform (I happen to know that quite some people misuse tearDown for this purpose), so I don't just want to delete it.

Well, it's got two reopen votes so far, and one is mine. It's mostly up to luck at this point whether someone else sees it and thinks it's worth reopening.
